# While loop doesn't work Stored-Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on stored-procedure and I have a while loop what contains a update query:

- @tmp_ID : Row's ID in table variable
- @secondcolumn (for example) : pseudocode@gmail.com;pseudocode@hotmail.com;
- @splitString (for example) : pseudocode (I search this value in tblusers and return true mail address)
- True values in tblusers : pseudocode@hotmail.com
- @mailadresses must has this value: pseudocode@hotmail.com;pseudocode@hotmail.com;

And query should update @columnname of @tablename as 'pseudocode@hotmail.com;pseudocode@hotmail.com;'

```
if (CHARINDEX(';',@secondcolumn) > 0)
        Begin

            While(CHARINDEX(';',@secondcolumn) > 0)
                begin

                    Set @splitMail =SUBSTRING(@secondcolumn,0,CHARINDEX(';',@secondcolumn))

                    Set @splitString = SUBSTRING(@splitMail,0,CHARINDEX('@',@splitMail))

                    Set @q_searchinUsers = 'Select Distinct @splitString_R = eMail from tblusers Where eMail like ''%' + @splitString + '%'''
                    EXEC sp_executesql @q_searchinUsers , N'@splitString_R nvarchar(max) output',@splitString_R OUTPUT

                    Set @mailadresses= @mailadresses+ @splitString_R +';'

                    SET @secondcolumn = REPLACE(@secondcolumn,@splitMail + ';' , '')
                end

                Set @q_updateQuery = 'Update '+ quotename(@tablename) +' Set '+@columnname+' = ''' + @mailadresses+ ''' Where ID = ' + convert(varchar,@tmp_ID) + ''

                Exec sp_executesql @q_updateQuery 
        End
```

When I run procedure, it says 'Command(s) completed successfully.' But it doesn't update the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `@tmp_ID`, is there any data present for this value in table

Comment: Yes, There is a data which has @tmp_ID value in my table

Comment: Try PRINT statement on @q_updateQuery. You will know if your update query is good or not

Comment: You're right, but I can't debug my stored procedure. It is about my authorisation.

Comment: If you cant debug than create a logtable and insert @q_updateQuery into that log table so you can read it there. Also write @@ROWCOUNT after the exec in that logtable. It is poor debugging but it least it is debugging

Comment: I would suggest that you execute the code you have (without the update statement) in a new query window with PRINT statements to see what the statements are, and what the various values are. In this way you can debug the code outside of the SProc and find the issue.